# Background images flickering on reload same route

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, caching, ionic4

I'm having an ionic app with a fullscreen  background image and when I navigate to the same route with different parameters the background image is flickering.

For testing purposes I used urls of pixabay images, and there was no flicker effect at all, now that I use my local (in the app) stored images, it flickers. (The images are small in size, around 200kb)  So I assume that there is some kind of caching problem?

Implementation of the background image:

```
<ion-content 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + sceneBackground + ')'}"
  class="backgound-image ion-no-padding"
  routerDirection="root">
```

The Link

```
<a class="fullLink"
            [routerLink]="['/page', bId, cId, nId"
            routerDirection="root"
            *ngIf="content[currentPos].type !== 'index'">
```

---

The Image from URL is loaded without a request, for the local image there's always a request, how can I cache a local file in ionic to prevent the request?

URL request:

```
Summary
URL: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/11/23/55/redwood-national-park-1587301_1280.jpg
Status: 200 OK
Source: Disk Cache
Initiator: 
platform-browser.js:2817


Request
No request, served from the disk cache.
```

Local request:

```
Summary
URL: http://localhost:4200/assets/scenes/scene-office.jpg
Status: 304 Not Modified
Source: Memory Cache
Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Initiator: 
platform-browser.js:2817


Request
GET /assets/scenes/scene-office.jpg HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,video/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-None-Match: W/"48bd6-1wY/xftZTec7f4u3zn/RZL/oTKg"
Host: localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-us
Referer: http://localhost:4200/red/1/77
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, mostly likely the server that serves your images isn't telling the browser to cache them.

When you used pixabay, those were likely being cached.